# aklog: Cannot allocate memory while converting principal to Kerberos V4 format

Tags: macos, openafs

I'm getting this error when executing aklog on my Mac OS. I think this happened after I moved to Mavericks.

Comment: I already upgraded to the newest OpenAFS:
Maintenance Release: OpenAFS 1.6.6 for MacOS 10.9 (Mavericks)
but I get the same error.

Comment: Can you post the exact output of what happens when you run aklog with -d? And post the full path to the aklog you are running (`which aklog`). Obfuscate the names/realms if you want, but having the output is just helpful to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

The code path for that error message should not exist in an aklog built for Mavericks, I don't think (HAVE_NO_KRB5_524 should be defined, which avoids the call to krb5_524_conv_principal). Is it maybe possible you are executing a different aklog than provided in the .dmg? Try running `which aklog` to see where the aklog is running from, or try extracting the aklog from the binary you download from openafs.org, and running that directly, to see if you get different results.